# In refrence to tkinter what does this warning mean?

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

[Warning here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEqbx.png)
**See the Warning at the bottom side of the code in the image.**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import font
try:
    from ctypes import windll
    windll.shcore.SetDpiAwareness(1)
except Exception as e:
    pass


class DistanceConvertor(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, **args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**args, **kwargs)

        self.title('Distance Convertor')
        self.geometry('600x600')
        self.resizable(False, False)

        self.frame = MetersToFeet(self, padding=(60, 30))
        self.frame.grid()

        self.bind('<Return>', self.frame.calculate_feet)
        self.bind('KP_Enter', self.frame.calculate_feet)

class MetersToFeet(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(container, **kwargs)

        self.feet_value = tk.StringVar
        self.metres_value = tk.StringVar

        meters_label = ttk.Label(self, text ='Metres:')
        meters_input = ttk.Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=self.metres_value)
        feet_label = ttk.Label(self, text='Feet:')
        feet_display = ttk.Label(self, textvariable=self.feet_value)
        calc_button = ttk.Button(self, text='CALCULATE', command=self.calculate_feet)

        meters_label.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='W')
        meters_input.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='E')
        feet_label.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='W')
        feet_display.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky='EW')
        calc_button.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky='EW')

        for child in self.winfo_children():
            child._grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

    def calculate_feet(self, *args):
        try:
            metres = float(self.metres_value.get())
            feet = metres*3.2884
            self.feet_value.set(f'{feet: .3f}')
        except ValueError:
            pass

root = DistanceConvertor()

root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
font.nametofont('TkDefaultFont').configure(size=15)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is more of a PyCharm question than anything. PyCharm will warn about many things that may or may not be of any concern. That said you do not actually describe the warning in your question but link to an image. Please reduce your code down to something simple that can reproduce the warning. IE get rid of code that is not needed. Like your binds and try/except statement.

Comment: Why do you care about warnings? I usually ignore them, because they don't really affect your program.

Answer (score 1):

By convention, class methods that begin with an underscore are considered to be "protected", meaning you should never call them outside of the class. In this case you're calling `_grid_configure`, so this warning is suggesting you shouldn't do that.

Tkinter widgets have a public method named `grid_configure` (without the leading underscore) that you should be using instead.